# Periodic updates of Windows 8 live Tile

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro

Say, I want to update the windows 8 live tile periodically, say after 10 seconds. Is there any way to achieve that? I am using metro xaml c# in windows 8.

Here's the code I am writing on Dispatcher Timer's Tick event:

```
switch(imageIndex)
{
    case  0:
        imageUrl = "Assets/Image1.png";
        break;
    case 1:
        imageUrl = "Assets/Image1.png";
        break;
    case 2:
        imageUrl = "Assets/Image1.png";
        break;        
}

ITileWIdeImageAndText01 tileContent = TileContentFactory.CreateTileWideImageAndText01();
tileContent.TextCaptionWrap.Text = "Hello";
tileContent.Image.Src = imageUrl;
tileContent.Image.Alt = "";

ITileSquareImage squareContent = TileContentFactory.CreateTileSquareImage();
squareContent.Image.Src = imageUrl;
squareContent.Image.Alt = "";
tileContent.SquareContent = squareContent;

TileUpdateManager.CreateTileUpdaterForApplication().Update(tileContent.CreateNotification());
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what do u want to update in live tiles?? Images or text???

Comment: sorry I wasnt clear with my question. I want to update the images. I have three images which I want to show after 10 seconds. Right now I am able to do that using DispatcherTimer but the images are changing in a flash. They are not getting animated as I see the other default tiles getting animated

Answer (score 0):

Don't use Dispatcher Timer as it will slow your app. You can use the following in your page Initializer:

```
TileUpdateManager.CreateTileUpdaterForApplication().EnableNotificationQueue(true);
```

Comment: EnableNotificationQueue wont provide me periodic updates... The notifications dont recur....

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you should do it:

```
switch(imageIndex)
{
    case  0:
        imageUrl = "Assets/Image1.png";
        break;
    case 1:
        imageUrl = "Assets/Image1.png";
        break;
    case 2:
        imageUrl = "Assets/Image1.png";
        break;        
}

ITileWIdeImageAndText01 tileContent = TileContentFactory.CreateTileWideImageAndText01();
tileContent.TextCaptionWrap.Text = "Hello";
tileContent.Image.Src = imageUrl;
tileContent.Image.Alt = "";

ITileSquareImage squareContent = TileContentFactory.CreateTileSquareImage();
squareContent.Image.Src = imageUrl;
squareContent.Image.Alt = "";
tileContent.SquareContent = squareContent;


var updater = TileUpdateManager.CreateTileUpdaterForApplication();
updater.EnableNotificationQueue(true);

updater.AddToSchedule(
    new ScheduledTileNotification(
        tileContent.CreateNotification(), 
        DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(10))
    { 
           ExpirationTime=DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddSeconds(20)
    });
```

This will result in a notification coming up 10 seconds after you started the app. And it will be expired 10 more second later.

(Also, maybe you should look into background services, because this particular solution might not be the best for what you want...)

Comment: Thanks Tenshiko. I'll give your solution a try. Good day.